# GWT SuggestBox -> onChange event

Tags: gwt, uibinder

Am confused bit time trying to understand how to capture SuggestionBox onchange() event in UiBinder.

Any help is greatly appreciated. The following code doesn't work:

```
@UiHandler( "singleRuleTemplateLeftSuggestBox" )
        void onChangeLeftOperand( ChangeEvent e ) {
            for ( OperatorProxy operator : operatorValues ) {
                operatorSuggestions.add( operator.getOperatorName() );
            }
        }
```

another attempt:

```
singleRuleTemplateLeftSuggestBox.getValueBox().addChangeHandler( new ChangeHandler() {

    @Override
    public void onChange( ChangeEvent event ) {
        System.out.println( singleRuleTemplateLeftSuggestBox.getValue() );
    }
} );
```

Answer (score 1):

`SuggestBox` does not implement `HasChangeHandlers` interface (only the old deprecated `SourcesChangeEvents`). So you need to either create an extended `SuggestBox` that implements such interface delegating the `addChangeHandler()` to the inner `ValueBoxBase<String>`, or attach the `ChangeHandler` on the `ValueBoxBase<String>` itself (via `suggestBox.getValueBox()`).

Comment: Hi I tried that and updated the code in my question. But it doesn't seem to work. Kindly help if am doing anything wrong here

Comment: First, you'd better off using `Window.alert()` or a logging facility (put simply `GWT.log()`), instead relying on `System.out.println`. Second, I'm thinking that you probably do not want to use the DOM-related `ChangeEvent`, but instead the GWT-provided `ValueChangeEvent` or `SelectionEvent` (both supported by `SuggestBox`). In that case, simply change your first `UiBinder` snippet to use them, depending on what is your purpose.